# How do I get an unreleased rosdoc code API on the wiki?

Tags: ros, rosdoc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The only API links are to the previously-released Electric and Fuerte versions.

I'd like to link the current repo master docs for review purposes. How can I get the rosdoc indexer to publish that?

EDIT: Or, is there a reasonable way to up-load it myself?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34610/how-do-i-get-an-unreleased-rosdoc-code-api-on-the-wiki?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2012-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosdoc generation is based on the development branch declared for each rosdistro in the appropriate rosdistro file.  When the job runs it will update with new commits, and is does not require a rerelease to see your new documentation.

When we spin up groovy you can set your new trunk in it's rosdistro file and it will be added to the index.  Right now you could put it into the unstable rosdistro, but that is slated to be retired soon.  Adding groovy and removing unstable should happen soon.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-26**:
That's great, thanks!